# How can I make a hard drive be recognized by my desktop PC BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

I have a quite old desktop PC which I want to get it back working. I had took away its hard drive, formated it and used it was external storage using a SATA-USB adapter.

Now I want to use it again and I can't make my BIOS see it. What's strange is that I can still plug it to my linux laptop using a SATA-USB adapter, so it can be mounted and store files to it. I've already formated it to either FAT32 and NTFS.

My BIOS is only showing a enable/disable SATA Controller option but any about IDE/SATA/RAID settings. I already did a CMOS reset.

But even tested different SATA cables and different ports at the motherboard BIOS won't see it.
My motherboard model is a MS-7525 V 1.0 and my Hard Drive is a Barracuda 7200 from Seagate.

I wonder whether I should test out the drive to be healthy and what's best way to do this.

Comment: Some further questions and hints. Please add exact model of your hdd. Did you try all 4 sata ports on your motherboard? Did this exact hdd work earlier or was that a different hdd (that's not clear to me)? Try running hirens boot cd or gparted live cd. Is the hdd not visible to those tools either? Does your hdd power up and spin up? Any unfamiliar noise from the hdd when in the pc during boot? Does the bios run longer than usual or display a hex status code for more than 3 seconds? Try to upgrade your bios. Running a diag on your hdd never hurts, but I guess that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test it would be live boot of GParted or whatever operating system if that can see that disk. Just be sure that you have connected SATA and SATA power cables, you should hear your disk spinning when you turn on PC.